# Как организовать связь между php и angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Приветствую!

Имеем, для примера, такую функцию в главном контроллере:

```
self.calculate = function (event) {
    var input_value = event.currentTarget.value;
    console.log(input_value); // Здесь всё хорошо, всегда выводит то, что надо.
    $http.get('base/calc_logic.php?t=1', {formula: input_value}).success(function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log('data:', data);
    });
};
```

Файл `calc_logic.php` содержит вывод полученных данных:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $val) {
    echo 'Key: [' . $key . '] -> Val: [' . $val . "]\n\r";
}
```

Ну и соответственно, что бы не было в переменной `input_value`, выводит всегда только

```
success
data: Key: [t] -> Val: [1]
```

Гугл упорно не выдаёт ничего полезного, может кто подскажет?

Comment: @A1essandro, я передаю параметр `{formula: input_value}`, который "теряется")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы передать данные, нужно вторым аргументом передать `{params: data}`. В итоге: 
`$http.get('base/calc_logic.php?t=1',{params:{formula:input_value}})...`.

Comment: вообще ничего не возращает (

Comment: Если Вы через GoogleChrome - нажмите f12 -> network, отправьте запрос, у Вас он отобразится, Вам нужно посмотреть на отправляемые данные (request)

Comment: Спасибо, метадом научного тыка определил что всему виной `formula`, заменил на `f`, и всё прекрасно передало, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS работает немножко не так. Для отправки параметров как вы хотите, нужно их обернуть в `{params : {formula: input_value}}`. Должно получиться так:

```
self.calculate = function (event) {
    var input_value = event.currentTarget.value;
    console.log(input_value); 

    $http.get('base/calc_logic.php?t=1', {params : {formula: input_value}})
         .success(function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log('data:', data);
    });
};
```

Comment: вообще ничего не возращает (

Comment: Спасибо, метадом научного тыка определил что всему виной `formula`, заменил на `f`, и всё прекрасно передало, спасибо!

Comment: Это хорошо, что заработало. Проверил с отправкой formula, все также работает, [Вот пример](https://plnkr.co/edit/crgjaNj37p8PjzBBH16c?p=preview), посмотрите в консоли, какой идет запрос.

Comment: Странно, ведь у меня нигде не используется эта переменная.
А код у меня почему-то не работает :)